# How to check for UISegmentControl particular segment is enabled or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

For UISegmentControl I have used [segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0] Is there any way to check whether particular segment is enabled or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
[segmentedControl isEnabledForSegmentAtIndex:0];
```